# Xamarin unique file path to media gallery Item

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, gallery

I'm using Xamarin with Visual Studio + the Media Plugin by [Media Plugin by James Montemagno](https://components.xamarin.com/view/mediaplugin).

I'm using it to **access the native device gallery**, using PickVideoAsync() to **choose/pick a video**.

```
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickVideoAsync();
```

I want to get the **full path of the video** (`var file`) I'm picking.

However, the resulting file seems to be a **temporary** (and compressed) **version of the actual file**. Therefore the path this file is referring to is not the original file path.

My Results:

```
file.Path: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9436142C-F8A1-43BF-ADE9-AD2DD676FC65/Documents/temp/trim.33800B19-DCDE-4629-896F-B34F5CDFB768.MOV

file.AlbumPath: assets-library://asset/asset.mov?id=8938D860-B84F-4878-9EA2-E91CBF9E9157&ext=mov
```

`file.Path`  = temporary filepath

`file.AlbumPath` = seems to be a unique "path" that refers to the file no matter what changes are applied to the gallery.
Sadly, this file seems to be an URI/URL.

How to get the **actual path**, or at least the **actual file name**?

**Hint:** `var file` is from type something like `Media.Plugin.Abstractions.MediaFile` as far as I remember, so it's not an actual .NET type